# Linux VPN - what to do after getting connected

Tags: linux, vpn

Update: My client forgot to forward an email from peak10 (with the IPs for two servers)!

Since I and some other people have put in some efforts (either way :) ), let me document the steps to get VPN connected on windows:

Install: http://forticlient-ssl-vpn.software.informer.com/

Ask tech support for the address to use for connection, it may be different than the other IPs you have got. You will need a username and a password. You can keep domain blank. Press connect. After few seconds, it will say connected (very silently).

If the server you are connecting with is Linux - use putty to ssh using the server IP. If you are connecting to windows use RDP. You will need respective usernames and passwords. If you don't know this information ask the tech support or your system admin or check the emails you have got from the hosting company.

Hope this helps someone

---

Updating the question:

- My client has managed service from peak10.
- Client gave me some details and I figured some with the support at peak10. I have two environment settings, saying:

> ```
> Network Block: some values
>
> Usable IP Range: some values
>
> Subnet Mask: some values
>
> Gateway: some values
>
> Broadcast: some values
> ```

- Tried to connect through VPN using Linux but could not [if you can help with this, that would be great!]. Their support was also unable to help in this. But they knew how to do it in windows so they asked me to install forticlient-ssl-vpn. After some more fiddling, it worked.
- Now what? I am stuck at this step. I tried to ssh to server using Putty and it did not work. I am able to ping one of the internal IP addresses. I tried to do windows style //ip-address, it did not give any error but did not show any files as well. Which means nothing is shared or it is not a windows server (which is a good thing - so its probably linux).
- Client is asleep at the moment and i need to do this stuff quickly. Any help or pointers would work. I am sufficiently technical about the stuff, but this situation ocured to me for the first time so I don't really know what to ask?
- Please feel free to put -1s but do help me. Thanks :)

Update: Output of route print

```
D:\Users\ppp>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 35...........................fortissl
 11...00 24 1d fa 8c f5 ......Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) Family PCI-E Gigabit
Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 18 4d 08 c3 d9 ......NETGEAR WG111v2 54Mbps Wireless USB 2.0 Adapter
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.10     25
         10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    276
     68.71.108.28  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.10     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.16.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.1     20
     172.16.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    276
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.10    281
     192.168.0.10  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.10    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.10    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.10    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.10    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 13     58 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13     58 2001::/32                On-link
 13    306 2001:0:4137:9e76:24ad:ab5e:49bb:c915/128
                                    On-link
 12    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    306 fe80::24ad:ab5e:49bb:c915/128
                                    On-link
 12    281 fe80::d1ac:6f18:f860:cc4f/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

### Old question below

I need to setup a website for one of my clients and they have bought managed services from peak10. It is linux server. I use linux(fedora) on my laptop and tried to connect through VPN using the settings provided. But it didn't work on Linux. After about 5-6 hours on phone with their support, we were able to connect using my Windows 7 machine through a software called forticlient-ssl-vpn.

Now what? Their support says they have done their job by getting me connected to their server. How to I access files on the server? And more importantly, how do I SSH to the server.

Also. one more thing the support guy told me that they are using ipsec.

My problem is that I don't know much about this stuff and am running out of time. I don't even know what question to ask. Please help me.

Comment: You're out of your depth, you need to come clean with your client and/or your employer.

Comment: Thats right. But what question should i ask? I know I am not a server admin. I am a web developer.

Comment: Moreover, I dont really use windows much. The problem is the server is a Linux server, it got connected through a windows pc. I tried to ssh using putty but its not working.

Comment: Then you should ask your client/employer who your sysadmin is.  Your question above is a non-question.  If you want help, you'll need to give specific examples, error messages, more detail and have some kind of actual problem in mind.  It's unusual to have to VPN into a hosting account for a start, are you sure you're not VPN'ing to the client's network.

Comment: Its very easy to post -1 and say stuff but its very difficult to help someone! I would learn this stuff but I wont post comments like yours.. see my profile in stackoverflow.. I help people where I can.

Comment: It's easy to help people when they have a specific problem, if I posted to stackoverflow with 'my employer wants me to write a ruby app, how do I open a text editor' you'd tell me I was out of my depth.

Comment: @EightBitTony  - to your second question: Yes, that did point me to thinking some more.. the client is asleep at the moment. I need to deliver somthing next morning. So I am left to figure things out.

Comment: @EightBitTony: As I said in the question itself, I dont even know what to ask. So your second comment did point me to something.

Comment: And I tried to google Linux VPN ipsec ... you are right its something out of scope for me now. But what I need is pointers to right direction.

Comment: I am mostly on the other end of things, where I receive SSH access and I setup Ruby, Rails etc.. and copy my code over and be done with. This is a new problem for me.

Comment: Why are you setting up Ruby and Rails?  The client's sysadmin should do that, and you should, at most, have to use a Capistrano recipe to deploy your app.

Comment: good question. but they expect us to be a network admin + system admin + programmer + .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But they knew how to do it in windows so they asked me to install
>   forticlient-ssl-vpn. After some more fiddling, it worked.

Go to command prompt, and give us the output of `route print`?

> I tried to ssh to server using Putty and it did not work. I am able to
>   ping one of the internal IP addresses.

Is it the SSH server's IP? Can you `telnet` to port 22?

> I tried to do windows style //ip-address, it did not give any error
>   but did not show any files as well. Which means nothing is shared or
>   it is not a windows server

OK. This is a linux server.

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface    Metric    
    172.16.1.0         255.255.255.0        On-link          10.0.0.1     20
   192.168.0.0         255.255.255.0        On-link      192.168.0.10    281
```

Pay attention to `Gateway` column, it shows `On-link`. It sounds like you have another problem with your vpn which I'm facing.

---

**Edited**

If the `On-link` problem stops you pinging to SSH server, you can add a static route:

```
route ADD [your SSH server's IP] MASK [subnet mask] [your VPN gateway] IF 35
```

`35` is the interface index of `fortissl` - your VPN interface. It is changeable everytime you connect to VPN.

Comment: +1 for trying to help me. I have updated the question with the output of route print.

Comment: What is your SSH server's IP? Can you `ping` and `telnet`?

Comment: This was question I asked the tech support... my client forgot to send one email with these details!

Comment: I am selecting your answer as it did point me to asking some correct questions to the client and which eventually solved my problem.

Comment: Let me know when you fully solve your problem. I will update my answer to give you a tip about `On-link` issue.